# Chatter status update box missing in Salesforce

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I'm logged into our Salesforce system as a user under the Administrator role, and with an elevated profile. I have enabled chatter. I am able to follow people, and they are able to follow me. I can comment on posts and attach files to posts. The version is Salesforce 2015.

*However*, I cannot post my own status updates (other than system-generated posts). How can I post my own status updates? I expected there to be a status textbox, as seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cvGvSCTgLA&t=0m4s

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this in more than one browser?  If I have problems in Salesforce in Chrome, I'll try Firefox too to confirm that it's a problem in both.  I've encountered situations where Salesforce features aren't available in Chrome.

Comment: @Jagular thanks for the tip, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, someone updated the Global Publishing layout to no longer include the *Post* and *File* actions. I re-added these actions by editing the Global Publishing layout at *Setup -> Build -> Create -> Global Actions -> Publisher Layouts*